# unable to enter form fields into database?

Tags: php, forms

i am currently having problem, pushing form fields into database. here is my html code:

```
<form action=""  method="post">
<p>Gender:</p><input type="radio" value="Male" name="gender">Male</input>
<input type="radio" value="Female" name="gender">Female</input><br>
<p>Birthday :</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="Help VITians to wish you."></input><br>
<p>Relationship :</p>
<select name="relation">
<option value="I don't want to say">I dont want to say</option>
<option value="Single">Single</option>
<option value="In a Relationship">In a Relationship</option>
</select><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="basic" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
```

and here is my php code:

```
<?php
  $senddata = @$_POST['basic'];

  //Password variables
  $gender = strip_tags(@$_POST['gender']);
  $birthday = strip_tags(@$_POST['birthday']);
  $relation = strip_tags(@$_POST['relation']);

  if ($senddata) {
  //If the form has been submitted ..
        //Check whether old password equals $db_password
            if (strlen($birthday) <= 4) {
             echo "Sorry! Birthday is not right! Try entering it in DD/MM/YYYY format.";
            }
            else if(empty($birthday)){
            echo "Please enter your Birthday";
            }
            else
            {
           $update_query = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE users SET gender='$gender', birthday='$birthday',relation='$relation' WHERE username='$user'");
           echo "Success! Your basic information has been updated!";

            }
         }
         else
         {
         }
?>
```

, but i am unable to enter into database and also my php code doesn't show error messages on the same page. is there are any errors?

Comment: what message it prints "success ..." or "Please enter ...." ?

Comment: from where $user come?

Comment: did you  declare your database connection "$conn" ??

Comment: there is no feild named 'birthday',
<input type="text" placeholder="Help VITians to wish you."></input>
it should be <input type="text" placeholder="Help VITians to wish you." name="birthday"></input>

Comment: You have serious SQL injection issues here, don't go live without fixing.

Comment: @halfer yeah, i know. thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First give name in birthday input set the database connection (if not set) and I can't see `$user` anywhere in the code. Please check first `$user` has any value or not than proceed like this:

```
$update = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE `users` SET `gender`='".$gender."', `birthday`='".$birthday."',`relation`='".$relation."' WHERE `username`='".$user."'");
```

Comment: When answering questions with a serious security flaw, it is important not to replicate it in your answer. Ideally a fixed should be suggested, or at least note to the OP what security issue they are facing.

Comment: @halfer ok i got it !!

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with your where condation and mysql connection also.

Please declare $user and $conn.

```
$user = "usernameindb";

//DATA BASE CONNECTION

$servername = "localhost";

$username = "username";

$password = "password";

$dbname = "myDB";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$update_query = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE `users` SET `gender`='".$gender."', `birthday`='".$birthday."',`relation`='".$relation."' WHERE `username`='".$user."'");
```

Comment: Consider what happens if a user enters a `gender` value of `'` (apostrophe)?